# masterCategories endpoint not honoring URL params

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

The masterCategories endpoint for getting Outlook categories is not honoring URL params such as $filter, and always returns a list of all available categories.
For example, running the following URL:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/outlook/masterCategories?$filter=displayName eq 'Red Category'`

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('fba2b653-cf1f-4bfa-a2f0-74d747664319')/outlook/masterCategories",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "6a8ad746-4e29-4023-bb59-76284e21a2f2",
            "displayName": "Red category",
            "color": "preset0"
        },
        {
            "id": "cc159c4a-5bc2-41fd-87ac-aa32649544da",
            "displayName": "Orange category",
            "color": "preset1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3221eb3f-09ef-4a8e-af75-1f66b017eff4",
            "displayName": "Yellow category",
            "color": "preset3"
        },
        {
            "id": "ba28758c-2906-406a-9c8b-01d4c41fc360",
            "displayName": "Green category",
            "color": "preset4"
        },
        {
            "id": "89991f45-acab-46ef-a70b-fc495f9f405b",
            "displayName": "Blue category",
            "color": "preset7"
        },
        {
            "id": "407b033d-af4a-47da-857f-6c1058a5e97d",
            "displayName": "Purple category",
            "color": "preset8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a known issue with this endpoint? Is there a workaround to get categories without falling back to using Outlook REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The categories entity does not support `$filter`.

Here's a snippet from [$filter's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter):

> Support for these operators varies by entity and some properties
> support $filter only with advanced queries. See the specific resource
> documentation for details.

The `categories` entity [does not mention supporting $filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-mastercategories) so it isn't supported.

Other entities such as `contacts` support it, so they [mention it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) as well as which fields it support (spoiler - email address only)